# How to set the parameters of reduction layer in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I want to turn a n1*c1*h1*w1 blob to n1*1*h1*w1(using sum), what parameters should I set when using reduction layer?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: from documentation http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/reduction.html your operation is not supported using reduction layer currently as it sums all the tail layers.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what layer should I use?@lnman

Comment: You can probably use convolutional layer to sum the channels using `1X1XC1` with weight 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try.@lnman

Comment: How could I make sure that the weight remain unchanged during fine-tuning?@lnman

Comment: @JunfuLiu set lr_mult for the conv to zero. don't forget to set bias_term: false

Comment: Thank you and another question is that how to set the weight all 1 at the beginning? Seems that the "constant" type in weight_filler do not satisfy the needs.@Shai

Comment: what do you mean by constant type doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: Because the constant type will set all the parameters 0 at the beginning, while all 1 is what I needed.@lnman

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Slice` layer to separate all your channels into different blobs, and then an `Eltwise` layer to sum them up.

Comment: a fixed conv layer should be much more efficient